# How to load URL on launch in a WebView (OSX project)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I am just starting to develop mac apps and I want that the WebView a URL when the app start.Here's my code:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     WebView *myWebView;
    //other instance variables
}

@property

(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;

//other properties and methods

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**:

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *urlText = @"http://google.com";
    [[self.myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    return;
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

@end
```

How to load URL on launch in a WebView (OSX project)?

I think that the code work but when I try to connect the code with the WebView in Interface Builder,I can't find the "web view" in the list of outlets.
Thanks
I'have update my code following the last post but is still doesn't work.
Thanks again for you replies.

Comment: do @synthesize myWebView; ??

Comment: @iPatel with the latest LLVM you do not need to `@synthesize` any more.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!Now I can define the outlet "web view "from the app delegate menu.But is still not work:the web view doesn't load the url.

Comment: @Skynext: check the answer...need to add webkit framework

Comment: I have already added (since the beginning),...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hard to be sure what the issue is here, so a guess...

Which way are you dragging the connection in IB?

To connect your outlet you want to drag from the outlet shown in the Inspector to the web view:

[image: making the connection]

If you drag in the other way, from the web view to the App Delegate in the outline you are trying to connect an action.

You also have an issue in your code, your instance variable:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
   WebView *myWebView;
   //other instance variables
}
```

will not be used by your property:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet WebView *myWebView;
```

as your property is automatically synthesised and so will create an instance variable `_myWebView`. You should see a compiler warning to this effect.

This in turn means the statement:

```
[[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
```

will not do what you expect, as `myWebView` will be `nil` and not refer to your `WebView`. You should refer to the property as `self.myWebView`:

```
[[self.myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
```

With those changes you should see Google in your web view.

HTH

Answer (score 8):

You need to add WebKit framework.[image]

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

[image]

Comment: IBOutlets should be weak

Comment: @pshah: iOS vs OSX... In OSX you seldom close the window, they are still loaded and remains in the memory as compared to iOS where you dealloc and release on each pop of view and viewControllers. Does it make sense?

Comment: Doesn't matter in this toy example, but good practice nonetheless in case you refactor.

Comment: Outlet should be of type WKWebView ?

Comment: @Renascent: WKWebView in added later, and now we use it. This answer is from the old framework when it was WebView.