# Default website when web browser launches xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I have been creating my own web browser and have successfully done that in xcode. But then I wanted a certain url google for example to load when it first opens, now I have been having issues with this. If anyone can explain to me how to do this it would be great. I have tried multiple things in my ViewController class, but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code snippet, if there's something wrong with it could you tell me? :) thanks

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL))

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
            didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `self.webView.loadRequest` instead of `self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest`?

Comment: I get why this should work, but I am still getting an error: Value of type 'WebView' has no member 'loadRequest'.

Comment: See this for reference. although it's on objective c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921974/how-to-load-url-on-launch-in-a-webview-osx-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API changed quite a bit in Swift 3. Here is the code that works:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "https://www.google.com/"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        self.webView.mainFrame.load(request)
    }
}
```

All the `Foundation` classes dropped the `NS` prefix (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md) and because they [changed the way parameters work](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md), the `load` function changed quite a bit.

[image: window]

Comment: THanks for this. This was exactly what I was looking for. It's surprising how much it changed, but now I see it i can understand it! :)